# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout freeze title position in toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/header"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                    />
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ab_gradient_purple"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"></LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

When i open activity i have a next result. Title in toolbar not located in center. It located on top of toolbar.

[image]

When i scroll my list to top, Text in toolbar(actually the title) moved too. I dont want this effect. I want that when i scroll my list toolbar freeze text on his position.

[image]

And finally it looks ok in the end :

[image]

Comment: Thr is a method called setExpandedTitleGravity() in CollapsingToolbarLayout. do check it..